# Generate spring-configuration-metadata.json file in project files to push to version control

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Is there a way to have the spring-configuration-metadata.json file generated in the project files `resources/META-INF` (as opposed to `target\classes\META-INF\spring-configuration-metadata.json`) so that it can be pushed to version control on change?

Using `spring-boot-configuration-processor` dependency with `maven`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly glancing through the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-configuration-processor/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/MetadataStore.java) of the relevant part of the configuration processor implementation it looks like its hard coded.

Since the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` works during the "compile" phase of maven, you can probably move the generated file by using other maven plugins (like ant run plugin, filtering probably and so on and so forth). And this should be a direct answer to your question

However, to be honest I don't think you should store this file in version control system for two main reasons:

1. This file is not a source code in the sense that you or your co-workers should edit it manually.
2. If someone from your team does refactoring in IDE it may accidentally change stuff in the file, so it will be hard to keep it in-sync. The current implementation makes sure that it will be generated during the compilation process so that it won't happen. The compilation time overhead is negligible.

So bottom line I believe it should be kept in the target folder